# Set up git local env

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am a part of a team having repository on github. While I am amending some files the only way I can see the results (pdf artifacts) is to push my commits to github and download it from there.
I know that it could be done easier by setting up a local env. This way I can have my artifacts created locally.
I've searched for the guide that explains how to do it, but it seems like even after having my git set up I don't know how to generate files locally.

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit
alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
alias.spull=svn rebase
alias.spush=svn dcommit
alias.alias=!git config --list | grep 'alias\.' | sed 's/alias\.\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1\     => \2/' | sort
include.path=~/.gitcinclude
include.path=.githubconfig
include.path=.gitcredential
diff.exif.textconv=exif
credential.helper=osxkeychain
core.autocrlf=input
core.editor=sublime
color.ui=true
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
```

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive ?

Comment: @smarber to be more specific I have a Late file, which results in pdf artifact. Thanks for the link, but it seems like it simply creates an archive of files in the same way as you `Clone` repository on GitHub and `Download Zip`

Comment: @feedthemachine Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a Late file, which results in pdf artifact

I suppose you mean Latex, in which case you should get some pdf generator tool on your local machine (where you have your local Git repo, and are amending your Latex files)

For instance [`michaelgruber/vim-latex-pdf`](https://github.com/michaelgruber/vim-latex-pdf), or [dscape/pdflatex-as-a-service](https://github.com/dscape/pdflatex-as-a-service).
That way, you don't have to wait for that file to be pushed to GitHub.

Comment: Yes, Latex. Thank you

Comment: I’ve used Tex Store

Comment: @feedthemachine Do you have a link/URL for "Tex Store"?

Comment: Sorry, it's called [TexShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/). It's huge, like 2 GB in size, yet fixed my problem